# Tower of Hanoi using Dynamic Array: How can I add a new ring to a peg and move rings from peg to peg?

Tags: c++, arrays

This is an assignment given in class and I am still quite new to C++. We were told that we must use a dynamic array to create the Tower of Hanoi program. The main starts out like this:

```
int main()
{
    int ring_count, start_peg, end_peg, choice;
    bool stay_in_loop = true;

    cout << "Enter the number of rings on the first peg:\n" << endl;
    cin >> ring_count;
    Towers pegs(ring_count);
    cout << "The initialized pegs and rings:\n" << pegs << endl;

    /* infinite loop for user to enter options to perform
    * to solve the tower of hanoi till user asks for exit  */
    while (stay_in_loop)
    {
        cout << "Enter 1 to move a ring." << endl;
        cout << "Enter 2 to exit the program.\n" << endl;
        cin >> choice;

        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            cout << "Enter the ring on which the top ring is to be moved from." << endl;
            cin >> start_peg;
            cout << "Enter the peg to which the ring needs to moved to." << endl;
            cin >> end_peg;

//....etc.
```

Then there are two headers and corresponding .cpp files. One set for the pegs and one set for the rings. Here is the body of the class in the peg header:

```
public:
/* constructor inits the Peg
* with n rings. The diameter peg's
* rings are from one inch(on top) to
* nth inch(on the bottom). */
Peg(size_t n);

/* returns the number of rings on the peg. */
size_t many_rings()const;

/* returns the value of the diameter of the top most ring. */
size_t top_diameter()const;

/* adds a new ring to the peg. */
void add_ring_to_top(const value_type ring_diameter);

/* remove the topmost ring of the peg */
void remove_top_ring();

/* overload output operator to print the peg object
* along with its rings in a understable format. */
friend ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const Peg& p);

protected:
/* use appropriate data structure for the pegs */
value_type top_most;
size_type ringUsed;
size_type ringCapacity;
int *arr = new int[ringCapacity];

bool legal; // for telling move_ring function if the move is legal
```

In the ring header there is a function: `int move_ring(int start_peg, int end_peg);`

My issue is this: How can I use this code that was given to us to create the body of the functions `add_ring_to_top` and `move_ring` without having a different array and `ringUsed` for each peg. I've been working on this for quite a while and I don't need the entire solution but some direction would be greatly appreciated. If I am supposed to be using those `typedef` please help me understand how these may be used for this particular program, I have zero experience with them.

Comment: Why shouldn't you have a different array and `ringUsed` for each peg?

Comment: I don't know, I just assumed that was how it should be done because all the starter code I was given only had one of each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing `towers` to `rings` and making a `remove_top_ring` function...

This is what I came up with for `add_ring_to_top()`:

```
/* adds a new ring to the peg. 
* only works if peg isn't full
* and the new diameter is smaller
* than the existing top ring diameter. */

void Pegs::add_ring_to_top(const value_type ring_diameter, int peg_number) {

cout << "Adding ring of diameter: " << ring_diameter << " to the top" << endl;

if (peg_number == 1) { // if the choice is peg 1
    if (ringsUsed1 < (ringCapacity + 1)) { // Is the peg at maximum capacity?
        if (ringsUsed1 == 0) { // Is the peg empty?
            *arr1 = ring_diameter;
            ringsUsed1++;
            legal = true;
        }
        else {
            if (ring_diameter < *arr1) { // Is the new diameter lower than the topmost ring?
                value_type *xarr1 = new value_type[ringCapacity]; // New array
                *xarr1 = ring_diameter;
                for (unsigned int i = 1; i <= ringsUsed1 + 1; i++) {
                    xarr1[i] = arr1[i - 1];
                }
                delete[] arr1;
                arr1 = xarr1;
                ringsUsed1++;
                legal = true;
            }
            else {
                cout << "Error!" << endl;
                legal = false;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        cout << "Error!" << endl;
        legal = false;
    }
}
else if (peg_number == 2) {
    if (ringsUsed2 < (ringCapacity + 1)) { // Is the peg at maximum capacity?
        if (ringsUsed2 == 0) { // Is the peg empty?
            *arr2 = ring_diameter;
            ringsUsed2++;
            legal = true;
        }
        else {
            if (ring_diameter < *arr2) { // Is the new diameter lower than the topmost ring?
                value_type *xarr2 = new value_type[ringCapacity]; // New array
                *xarr2 = ring_diameter;
                for (unsigned int i = 1; i <= ringsUsed2 + 1; i++) {
                    xarr2[i] = arr2[i - 1];
                }
                delete[] arr2;
                arr2 = xarr2;
                ringsUsed2++;
                legal = true;
            }
            else {
                cout << "Error!" << endl;
                legal = false;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        cout << "Error!" << endl;
        legal = false;
    }
}
else {
    if (ringsUsed3 < (ringCapacity + 1)) { // Is the peg at maximum capacity?
        if (ringsUsed3 == 0) { // Is the peg empty?
            *arr3 = ring_diameter;
            ringsUsed3++;
            legal = true;
        }
        else {
            if (ring_diameter < *arr3) { // Is the new diameter lower than the topmost ring?
                value_type *xarr3 = new value_type[ringCapacity]; // New array
                *xarr3 = ring_diameter;
                for (unsigned int i = 1; i <= ringsUsed3 + 1; i++) {
                    xarr3[i] = arr3[i - 1];
                }
                delete[] arr3;
                arr3 = xarr3;
                ringsUsed3++;
                legal = true;
            }
            else {
                cout << "Error!" << endl;
                legal = false;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        cout << "Error!" << endl;
        legal = false;
    }
}
}
```

This is what I came up with for `move_ring()`:

```
/* top ring is moved from start peg to end peg.
* uses add function from Peg class.
* function also checks if move is legal or not
* and returns 1 if it is legal else returns 0. */

int Rings::move_ring(int start_peg, int end_peg) {

// attempt to move
if (start_peg == 1) {
    Pegs::add_ring_to_top(*arr1, end_peg);
    Pegs::remove_top_ring(1);
    if (Pegs::legal == true) {
        cout << "Success." << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Fail." << endl;
        return 0;
    }
}
else if (start_peg == 2) {
    Pegs::add_ring_to_top(*arr2, end_peg);
    Pegs::remove_top_ring(2);
    if (Pegs::legal == true) {
        cout << "Success." << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Fail." << endl;
        return 0;
    }
}
else if (start_peg == 3) {
    Pegs::add_ring_to_top(*arr3, end_peg);
    Pegs::remove_top_ring(3);
    if (Pegs::legal == true) {
        cout << "Success." << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Fail." << endl;
        return 0;
    }
}
else
    cout << "Error." << endl;
return 0;
}
```